# how to set sort order in the category browsing page of admin?

Tags: zen-cart

By default when we want to set the sort order of a product, we go the product details page and then set the sort order.

But I want to set the sort order of a product on the categories page where all the products are listing on the admin side.

Is there any option for this or a module to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the upper right hand side of the page admin->categories->categories/products, there's a dropdown with the label "Categories/Product Display Order."

Comment: but it is the sort order to display the products in that list. And I want to set the value of sort order of every product on that page so that I should no go to the product details page and set there? Hope you understood my question.

Comment: Ah ok.  There isn't such a module to the best of my knowledge.  You have to set it by editing the product.  You don't generally have to update the sort order so frequently that doing the two steps (selecting the product and then editing it) is considered that burdensome.

Comment: Ok, Could you please tell me about the files in which I should code so that I can set the sort order value of a product on the categories.php page?

Comment: admin/includes/modules/category_product_listing.php

Comment: I have added a text field and an update button for sort order next to sort column. But when I try to enter some text and click in the textfield it redirects me to the product details page. As there is javascript code on the row onclick event for redirecting the page to the product details page. So what should I do with this?